# is it possible to make a calculator more efficient? and if so, how?

Tags: python-3.x, calculator

Recently I've been trying to think about a better way to do a calculator.
because now I just do it manually like this:

```
if action == "+":
   answer = firstNum + secondNum
elif action == "*":
```

and so on with every sign...
how can I do this without having to do every sign manually??

Comment: cross-site duplicate: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/196961/basic-calculator-in-python

Answer (score -1):

As we don't have Switch in Python, you can do this:

```py
>>> a = '1+3'
>>> eval(a)
4

>>> t1 = 1
>>> t2 = 3
>>> eval('t1 + t2')
4

>>> exec(f'b = {a}')
>>> b
4
```

Else, you will need to do and `if/elif` statement for each one.
I recommend using `eval`, as `exec` executes dynamic code.
Idk if this have security problems *(probably)*, or performance problems.

**Edit1:** You should not use any of these **If you dont trust the origin** of the equation. If so, youll need to make more If and elses, or use DeepSpace's solution.

Comment: This does not have security problems, this is an entire security hole, especially if `action` can somehow be manipulated/inputted by the end-user. `eval` and `exec` are rarely the correct solution. In this case, using [a dict to map between `operator.*` methods to strings](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/196961/basic-calculator-in-python) is the correct solution